# XSL Transform : Choose block not choosing right variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-choose

I am working on an xsl document which keeps loosing lines of an address.
I had it fixed but seem to have broken it trying to fix an issue associated with the fix.
Here is a sample from my code:

.

```
  <addressLine2>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number($houseNameNumberNumericCharacterLength) &gt;= number($houseNameNumberNonNumericCharacterLength)">
                <xsl:value-of select="mad:Address/mad:AddressLineTwo"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$addressLineOne"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>                
        </xsl:choose>   
  </addressLine2>
  <addressLine3>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="addressLine2 != '$addressLineOne'">
                <xsl:value-of select="$addressLineThree"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$addressLineTwo"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
  </addressLine3>
  <addressLine4>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="addressLine3 = ($addressLineTwo)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$addressLineThree"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="mad:Address/mad:AddressLineFour"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
  </addressLine4>
```

You can assume AddressLine2 is always mapped to the variable $addressLineOne. AddressLine2 is working fine. 
The problem I am having is address line 3. I test

`when addressLine2 = $addressLineOne` then `choose value $addressLineThree`

But the address comes out like this:

```
Line1: (mapped from houseNumberHouseName)
Line2: $AddressLineOne
Line3: $AddressLineThree
Line4: /
```

What i need is:

```
Line1: (mapped from houseNumberHouseName)
Line2: $AddressLineOne
Line3: $AddressLineTwo
Line4: $AddressLineThree
```

and when AddressLine1 is not mapped from houseNumberHouseName:

```
Line1: $AddressLineOne
Line2: $AddressLineTwo
Line3: $AddressLineThree
Line4: /
```

Can someone please point out why my choose selects are not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can simplify like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number($houseNameNumberNumericCharacterLength) &gt;= number($houseNameNumberNonNumericCharacterLength)">
        <addressLine2><xsl:value-of select="mad:Address/mad:AddressLineTwo"/></addressLine2>
        <addressLine3><xsl:value-of select="$addressLineThree"/></addressLine3>
        <addressLine4><xsl:value-of select="mad:Address/mad:AddressLineFour"/></addressLine4>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <addressLine2><xsl:value-of select="$addressLineOne"/></addressLine2>
        <addressLine3><xsl:value-of select="$addressLineTwo"/></addressLine3>
        <addressLine4><xsl:value-of select="$addressLineThree"/></addressLine4>
    </xsl:otherwise>                
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: thank you, works great. Had attempted to continue along the form someone else had used, lacked the intuition to re think the conditions. Thanks for the quick reply